# how to adjust listview selection area?

Tags: listview, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I am working on a metro app project and I have listview.
In the listview there some items and I cant swipe to last of the list
I dont know why but all the area under the item is become the part of that item

is it possible to adjust the selection areo of that item so that I can swipe Under it

[image]

Comment: First, it appears you are panning horizontally. If this is the case, you should be using a `GridView`. If your `ItemTemplate` has a `Grid` just set its width explicitly.

Comment: when I use gridview samething happened when I put the next to each other the highlight and selectable area are same with the listview